# Real Projective plane $\mathbb{RP}^2$

Tags: geometric-topology, projective-varieties

I visited [this site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane#Cross-capped_disk) about Real Projective plane $\mathbb{RP}^2$, or $\mathbb{P}^2\bigl(\mathbb{R}\bigr)$ if you prefer. My problem is this: when I implement the first equation of the **Cross-capped disk** in **Geogebra** the result coincides with that shown in the figure below. But in the same site there is not written the equation of Figure 2. Could someone write the equation that I request, please?

To be clear the figure of which I request the surface equation is this:

[image: RP^2]

Thank you so much

Comment: This question is related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646483/real-projective-plane-with-tikz-pstricks) in which I request why the code that I wrote does not produce the Figure 2 in (the same site)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane#Cross-capped_disk]. If there is someone that could answer my previous question I would thank her/him a lot.

Comment: Let me suggest you take a look at our guidelines for [formatting and writing your question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992), with emphasis on *making your question visible*. You should not expect readers to click through to an external site to understand the pictures and equations you are asking about.

Comment: @Lee Mosher In my question I asked the equation of surface in that site. At maximum I can load the screenshot editing my question... . What else could I do to improve my question? Thx again

Comment: What kind of equation are you trying to find? (In your post, you did not specify.) Keep in mind that projective plane does not embed in the Euclidean 3-space, thus, pictures that you can possibly get will be misleading. It is best to focus on definitions and descriptions of projective plane as quotient spaces,  and learning how to work with these. You will learn nothing of value from the pictures that you are trying to draw.

Comment: I'm finding a surface equation. My real problem is this: I must implement this surface equation in TikZ for my thesis in Topology.

Comment: I looked at the pictures in the link. The second picture is the same as the first one, just rotated around the vertical axis. I do not see a math question here.

Comment: I edited my question adding a photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sufficient to restrict the domain of the variable $v$ of this surface equation from $[0,2\pi]$ to $[1,2\pi-1]$ or even $[\pi/3,5\pi/3]$:

\begin{equation}
\left[(1+\cos v)\cos u,(1+\cos v)\sin u,2\tanh(\pi-u)\sin v\right]
\end{equation}